# Set up a php server that can be accessed on my phone

Tags: php, http

I want to be able to set up a php server on my local machine, that will allow me to host php files so that I can access them via an IP address on my phone.

I would need ldap and oci libraries on this php server.

How could I do this?

Thanks,

Comment: Does your ISP give you a static and non-shared IP address? If not, this becomes quite difficult, to the point where you'd be better finding some cheap hosting instead.

Comment: @Dave More than enough free dynamic DNS services around, such as [No-IP Free](http://www.noip.com/personal/). No static IP required. Shared is a problem though.

Answer (score 0):

First, open a port in your router so that you can access your internal host's port from the outside world. For example, (outside) 80 -> (localmachine's ip) 80.

Then, get yourself a Dynamic DNS account (ex: noip.com) so that if your IP changes, you can still find it by your noip hostname (ex: antonywest.noip.com would point to your home IP)